# How to remove an element and add it at the end of an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. I'm trying to create a shuffle method for my Poker game java code. It's supposed to return 52 cards, shuffled. The instructions tell me to remove a card using math.random and return it at the end of the ArrayList, and do this a 500 times to shuffle it.

I'm confused as how I can add it back. This is all that I have so far... Thanks!

```
  public void shuffle()
  {

     int x = (int)(52 * Math.random());
     myDeck.remove(x);

  }
```

By the way, myDeck is the ArrayList name.

```
 ArrayList<Card> myDeck;
```

Comment: Where is “**500 times**?” Where is any try to “**return it at the end of the ArrayList**?”

Comment: I used for(int i=0; i<=500; i++). Also did myDeck.add(x) but gave me errors. "The method add(int, Card) in the type ArrayList<Card> is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Comment: @Oninez See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27244343/474189). You need to store the result of `remove()` and add it again.

Comment: On a theoretical note it's not clear why you keep selecting between 0 - 51 for 500 times. Why not select a card in the reducing range (52-i) for(int i=0;i<=51;++i)? Treating the random numbers as properly distributed that will guarantee a uniform distribution whereas (in theory) your method takes over 9x longer longer and doesn't quite guarantee a uniform distribution (there's a small chance it keeps shuffling the high end cards and leaves the start of the deck relatively untouched).

Comment: @Oninez Note that this question was easily answered by looking in [the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). They should be your first port of call when you wonder how to do things. The `add()` method is the first one listed, even.

Comment: @DanAllen I agree this method could be more efficient, but I suspect the OP is just following some simple instructions. I'm no statistician, but I question your premise that the current shuffle is not uniformly distributed. If the selection of the card is random (and uniformly distributed), then that ought to be sufficient. Yes, sometimes it will only shuffle parts of the deck but that's the whole idea behind randomness, no?

Comment: @Duncan, Think about running the OP method only 52 times. It's actually quite likely (36%) that the top card will be unchanged. It ought to be the top card at end of just under 2% of shuffles. Repeating that process again and again will gradually reduce the bias but can't erase it. I think you probably need millions of simulations to see a significant different but my real point is to do 9x more work for a slightly worse distribution. I estimate the bias as 0.0001% (shuffles of 500 that never touch card 0) which I would say is negligible in almost all applications. It was a theoretical note...

Comment: @DanAllen Thanks for the analysis. I should have stopped writing at "I'm not a statistician..." ;-)

Comment: @Duncan, I know I'm banging on but the world is full of poor simulations that don't take proper care of their bias. It would be interesting to see the probability that card index 25 (top of low half) also ends up in the first half of the deck or the first and last card end up in the same relative order. That's probably quite biased. I'll leave that as an exercise to the OP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the result of `remove()`:

```
Card card = myDeck.remove(x);
```

then add it again, which automatically places it at the end of the list:

```
myDeck.add(card);
```

Comment: Ahhh, this is great! Thanks a lot, I've been trying to find out how to make a new card that was of the card that I just took out and its been hours.... Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, save the value, remove it and re add it.

```
Card y = myDeck.get(x)
myDeck.remove(x);
myDeck.add(y);
```

Comment: `remove()` returns the object previously at that location, so you can do this in one fewer lines.